#  In Eretz Yisroel Kosher In  Chutz Laretz  Posul

Tags: sukkah, riddle, eretz-yisrael, chutz-laaretz

How is it possible you make a Sukkah with the same conditions and outside Israel it is not Kosher and inside Israel it is?

Comment: How long do we have to wait for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gershon Your first answer is right even though L'halacha in Chutz Laretz according to most it would be good to since you cant steal land.

Another answer is one of the Conditions Yeshouah made when going into Eretz Yisroel was that people could use each others Branches from his friends field granted it was only small branches Called  היזמי והיגי so using those in Eretz Yisroel the using of these branches is kosher in Chutz Laaretz you cant take from your Friends Field hence Sukkah is no good.

There is another Takanah made for the people being Oleh Regel that they be able to drink water from the puplic wells Posts where placed around it and they serve as an Eruv of sorts this Heter only works in Israel hence since it is a wall for Shabbos it is Halachicly also a wall for Sukkah In Eretz Yisreol but in Chutz Laaretz where it is not Muttar to Carr it would not Make a good Sukkah idf Schach Where placed on top.

Comment: There are more answers I do not have the patience to Type them up but feel free to Keep looking for more answers

Answer (score 2):

If you build a Sukkah in a public area - In Israel, this is allowed since permission is automatically granted to use the street for this purpose. However in Chutz Laretz this would make the Sukkah Posul unless permission was granted to have it built on that area.

Comment: I think we say, though, that it is kosher bidieved, if someone benched on a sukkah that was built in a public domain without explicit permission.

Comment: See the Rama in Orach Chaim 637:3 and the Mishna Berurah "ad Loc"

Comment: That is the best answer I was able to come up with. Do you have another one?

Comment: why is permission aautomatically granted?

Comment: I second @SimchasTorah's comment, why do you say it is automatically granted? Just because it is very common in certain neighborhoods, does not mean permission is granted. (This probably has more to do with Israeli *chutzpa* than any kind of implicit Israel permission... :-) )